# Time/space complexity of this algorithm to find letter combinations of a phone number?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am not sure of the time/space complexity for this because although it has a double for loop O(n^2), inside a for loop O(n), so O(n^3), it also has takes a digit and generates letter permutations, so kind of like O(n number of digits x m! permutations for the letters).

```
/**
 * @param {string} digits
 * @return {string[]}
 */

var permutate = function(currentCombinations, nextLetters) {
    var results = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < currentCombinations.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < nextLetters.length; j++) {
           results.push(currentCombinations[i] + nextLetters[j]);
       }
    }

    console.log(currentCombinations, '+', nextLetters, '=>', results);

    return results;
}

var letterCombinations = function(digits) {
    if (digits === "") return [];

    var phoneMap = ["0", "1", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"];

    var result = [""];

    for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        var letterMappingsForDigit = phoneMap[digits[i]];
        result = permutate(result, letterMappingsForDigit);
    }

    return result;
};

letterCombinations("23");
// => [ 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'cd', 'ce', 'cf' ]
```

Comment: can a digit used twice? eg: letterCombinations("111122223331123")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you won't use `phoneMap[i]` twice for same i, i.e. the ultimate call is `letterCombinations("0123....len(phoneMap)-1")`,

Then I think it is [image: formula] where *a[x]* is the length of *phoneMap[x]*

Consider the call of `letterCombinations("012")` and let the length of `phoneMap[1], phoneMap[2], phoneMap[3] be 3,5,2` respectively.

Then you algorithm will do the `O(1)` push for `1*3 + 1*3*5 + 1*3*5*2` times, which is

`a[0] + a[0]a[1] + a[0]a[1]a[2]` where `a = [len(phoneMap[0]), len(phoneMap[1]), len(phoneMap[2])]`

---

If a less tight bound is acceptable, I will assume you can reuse `phoneMap[i]`, then the complexity above can be simplifed as [image: formula2] where *L* is the longest string in `phoneMap` and *n* is the length of digits you pass into `letterCombinations`.

Because the above formula will become simple geometric sum, say `L = 5` and you call `letterCombinations("5555")`, then the sum is `5 + 5*5 + 5*5*5 + 5*5*5*5` = `5*(5^(n) - 1)/(5-1)` = `O(5^n)`